# Where should I ask a question about specific headphones?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My headphones recently broke and I'm looking to buy the exact same type, but I don't know anything other than the fact they are JBL ear-in headphones.  I have Googled its description, I have tried to find information by looking through the JBL website, and I have looked up "headphones stack exchange" to find where other people are asking questions like this, but most of the results I've seen are about trying to repair, troubleshoot, or design in headphone-related issues. I haven't had any luck so I've decided to turn to Meta.

### Which Stack Exchange can I use to help identify my headphones? I will be providing many pictures of the headphones from different angles and closeups, and I am simply looking for someone to identify them so I can then purchase them online.

Comment: Can you say which year you purchased them? Have you considered the fact that [the model might no longer be in production](https://eu.jbl.com/headphones)? There are over 30 models! Have you tried showing them to a specialist IT/audio/HiFi store and asking them to identify the model?

Comment: Find a clip of an actor using the same headphones in a sci-fi/fantasy movie and ask on [scifi.SE] :P

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh I'm pretty sure they aren't in production... the first time I bought them was probably 10 years ago at this point.  However, I'm sure that someone will be able to identify them and at least be able to recommend their nearest modern equivalent. I'm used to hearing things a very specific way  when I'm writing music.

Comment: Relying on one person to tell you one set of earphones sounds the same as another certainly places a lot of trust in a single person. JBL has a [refurbished](https://www.jbl.com/refurbished-headphones/) page if you want clean earphones that are used. There are [review sites](https://www.thephonograph.net/scores-comparison/) where people are particular. There's also [Google Images](https://images.google.com/) to compare your images with similar images. If yours are 100% trashed you can probably pop them open and there will be a name or model number inside.

Comment: @ChatterOne Absolutely not. Fixing of consumer electronics is out-of-scope at electronics.SE, as indicated by [their help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 8):

For questions pertaining to finding some headphone models fitting some description/requirements, you can try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones

For some other types of questions about headphones: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headphones

Comment: It seems like those questions don't get much attention at that SE... there are multiple questions with no responses at all.  I'm looking for somewhere there will be lots of people familiar with audio equipment.

Comment: While it sticks in my craw to suggest offsite resources, and they're often snobby - there's specialist headphone fora that might be of help.

Comment: A decent pic of the headphones would be a good start wherever you ask the question